# Using Jquery to remove text from div

Tags: jquery, css, html, replace

I'm using the following jQuery code to remove the text "(2012)" from a specific div.

```
var el = $("#myDiv");  
//replace(/word to remove/ig, "");  
el.html(el.html().replace(/(2012)/ig, ""));
```

This works great at removing the 2012, however the brackets () remain. How do I tell the jquery that the `()` is not code but text I wish to remove as well?

Comment: `var test = 'hello (2012)'; test.replace(/\s*\(2012\)\s*/,'');` -- Removes remaining whitespace as well. `el.text(el.text().replace(/(\s*\(2012\)\s*)/g,''));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use backslashes to escape the parentheses

```
var el = $("#myDiv");  
//replace(/word to remove/ig, "");  
el.html(el.html().replace(/\(2012\)/ig, ""));
```

Here's an example of it in [action](http://jsfiddle.net/Mnz93/).

Additionally you could simplify it like this:

```
var el = $("#myDiv");
el.replaceWith("");
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/eENMM/)

**Edit 3**:

Thanks to Ryan for pointing out that the i is not necessary. Also after farther consideration I realized that you may have more inside the div then just the date, in which case the following code should work best for you:

```
var el = $("#myDiv");
el.html(el.html().replace(/\(2012\)/, ""));
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/vMg2Z/)

Comment: the case insensitive option "i" is not necessary, but this is the most correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

try this: `.replace("(2012)","")`

no need for regex for something this simple.

Comment: This will not work if `(2012)` appears more than once in the div; however, we do not know if that will be an issue since they did not provide the content of the div.

Answer (score 0):

escape the parenthesis :

```
var str = "hello(2012)";
console.log(str.replace(/(\(2012\))/,''));​​​​​​
```